# how to use an https with qt network?

Tags: c++, qt, https, qtnetwork

I have a question about https and qt network.

I would like to know if I use https url, can I use the same code like http url or I must do some changes. Does someone can say which change I must do?

ps: I would like to auth to my https website and do get/post

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS will work with Qt so long as OpenSSL is available.

On Mac and Linux, this is typically an automatic.  On Windows, you will likely need to build and ship the OpenSSL 1.0.x binaries, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, with your application. If Qt can dynamically load these binaries at startup, HTTPS support will be available. Or rebuild Qt from source to statically link with the OpenSSL libraries.